# EKEventStore Programming Xcode iOS Asynchronous Search

Tags: ios, xcode, ekevent, ekeventstore

The Documentation states:

> - (void)enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
>                               usingBlock:(EKEventSearchCallback)block
>
> This method is synchronous. For asynchronous behavior, run the method on another thread with dispatch_async or NSOperation.

How do you make this asynchronous, the sentence doesn't really demonstrate it. Could anyone clarify?

Thanks

D :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either dispatch it all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        [store enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:p usingBlock:^(..) {
            //DO IT
        }];
    });
    ...
}
```

or the callbacks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    [store enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:p usingBlock:^(..) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        //DO IT
        });
    }];

    ...
}
```